# Subsubstring first two unless start with ZZ

Tags: r

I want to substring a string to get a location. I know the functions `substr` or `strsplit` but I need to split with a condition. Basically its always the first two letters, but if it starts with ZZ then it are the 2nd two letters

So as example:

```
Location  Expected_from_string_split
HJ 848    HJ
BP 231    BP
ZA 123    ZA
ZZ AB 123 AB
```

I tried to replace ZZ with " " so I can still split the string on first two letters, but with replace you replace the whole value. So that didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be:

```
substr(sub('ZZ ', '', df$Location), 1, 2)
```

Output:

```
[1] "HJ" "BP" "ZA" "AB"
```

Comment: when I try this I get unused argument 2, when I use it without saving it into a variable. I see a space with a letter, instead of two letters. Prob that the space takes up 1 letter.

Comment: You'll need to share `dput` of your data to solve this

Comment: I am sure there is a regex to do this but I am pretty useless with regex :)

Comment: Exactly my thoughts but also cannot help much and was too lazy to google :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df$Location_new <- gsub("^ZZ ", "", df$Location)
```

Output:

```
df
  Location Location_new
1       HJ           HJ
2       BP           BP
3       ZA           ZA
4    ZZ AB           AB
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Location = c("HJ", "BP", "ZA", "ZZ AB"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are unsure of the space between ZZ and the code, the following can be used for all different cases

```
address <- c("AP 12","RA 21","ZZLA 23","KS 12","ZZ  LL 12")
mod.address<-gsub("[Z][Z]\\s{0,}","",address)
state <- substr(mod.address,1,2)
print(state)
# OUTPUT
# [1] "AP" "RA" "LA" "KS" "LL"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `trimws` from `base R`

```
trimws(df$Location, whitespace = 'ZZ\\s*')
#[1] "HJ" "BP" "ZA" "AB"
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(Location = c("HJ", "BP", "ZA", "ZZ AB"))
```